# Types matter in array.prototype.includes(), but it is not intuitive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

While writing a sudoku solver, I ran into a issue which took me hours to solve which is based on `['1','2','3'].includes(3)`. is false. Since 3 in includes is a type number but 3 in array is type string. But this is against the intuition that type coercion happens while comparing values in js? Should it be corrected in js?
ex: `['1','2','3'].includes(3) // false`
and `['1','2','3'].includes('3') // true`

Throw some light on whether this is needed or should be fixed as it will lead to errors in programs if not checked carefully.

Comment: "*type coercion happens while comparing values in js*" - no, not always. `'3' === 3` is false as well.

Comment: Yes. But I thought it is very common. Most developers will overlook this and assumes type coercion happens in .includes and will lead to bugs.

Comment: Well, that's on them, not on `includes`. You should never write code that relies on comparison between different types.